# Get single column using Spring data JPA without query

Tags: java, jpa, spring-data-jpa

I am just trying to avoid writing query and fetch data based on method name convention. Below is my Entity

```
@Entity
class Product{
     @Id
     private Integer productId;
     private String productName;
     private String productStrategy;
}
```

I have below repository:

```
interface ProductRepository extends JPARepository<Product,Integer>{
        public Product findByProductStrategy(String productStrategy);
}
```

Above method and repository is working fine for me. But I am using only `productName` from the above result. So is there any way using which i can just fetch the `productName` instead of fetching hole record.

**Note: I know, we can achieve it using `@Query` by writing HQL query or native query. But i want to do it without writing query, just with the method name convention.**

Comment: is there a specific reason why you don't want to use HQL query?

Comment: are you only fetching the results or performing other crud actions also?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Consider using [Projections](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/reference/html/#projections) from spring data

Create a projection interface for your entity with the field that you want. In your case, it should look something like

```
public interface ProductName {
  String getProductName();
}
```

and then change your repository to have the return type of the projection interface itself. Spring will take care of the rest.

```
public interface ProductRepository extends JPARepository<Product,Integer>{
        public ProductName findByProductStrategy(String productStrategy);
}
```

Comment: I am aware of Projection concept. But i am just curious to know that if there is something in **method name convention** that can fulfill my requirement.

Comment: The projection concept is in-fact working on the method name convention

Comment: It will still fetch all of the columns, but then simply ignores the rest, and only maps the ones you defined in the projection. So eventually it will consume MORE resources than the default version.